# Using random forest regression for time series forecasting - valid approach?

Tags: time-series, regression, machine-learning-model

I'm working on predicting 7-day sales for a product using time series data. Though I primarily have experience in NLP and CV, I ventured into using ARIMA models for this task. However, the results didn't align well with my holdout set, as the ARIMA model was giving me a constant value for predictions on all 7 future days.

I then explored transforming the time series into a regression problem, using lagged features (e.g., lagging sales by days or weeks). With a RandomForestRegressor, I achieved acceptable RMSE and respectable Mean Bias Deviation. This approach was reminiscent of one used in the Walmart sales forecasting Kaggle challenge, and I wonder if others have successfully applied it to their time series data, and how well or poorly it worked on their dataset?

I've resampled my daily data to a weekly level and used TimeSeriesSplit from scikit-learn with n_splits=6. However, I haven't used max_train_size or test_size, and I'm concerned this might be causing data leakage, as my results seem overly optimistic. Here's an outline of my methodology:

1. Lagged Features: Created 8 lags on a weekly level.
2. Random Forest Model: Trained and evaluated using TimeSeriesSplit, with hyperparameter tuning for 'n_estimators', 'max_depth', 'min_samples_split', and 'min_samples_leaf'.

Can anyone share insights or experiences on transforming time series into a regression problem, especially regarding the potential data leakage issue with TimeSeriesSplit? Your expertise would be much appreciated!

Thank you!

Code:

````
# Function to create lagged features- here I create 8 lags on Week level
def create_lagged_features(series, lags=8):
    lagged_data = pd.concat([series.shift(i) for i in range(lags, 0, -1)], axis=1)
    lagged_data.columns = [f"lag_{i}" for i in range(lags, 0, -1)]
    lagged_data['target'] = series.values
    return lagged_data.dropna()

# Function to train and evaluate Random Forest model
def train_random_forest(X, y):
    # Time series cross-validation
    tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=6)

    # Random Forest model
    rf_model = RandomForestRegressor()

    # Hyperparameter tuning
    param_dist = {
        'n_estimators': [50, 100, 150, 200],
        'max_depth': [10, 20, 30, 40, None],
        'min_samples_split': [2, 5, 10],
        'min_samples_leaf': [1, 2, 4]
    }
    search_cv = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=rf_model, param_distributions=param_dist,
                                   scoring='neg_root_mean_squared_error',
                                   cv=tscv, verbose=2, n_jobs=-1, n_iter=50)
    search_cv.fit(X, y)
```
````

Comment: check out [Kaggle's time series tutorial](https://www.kaggle.com/learn/time-series), it is a good starting point.